# Must a certificate's issuer be listed in Java's 'cacert' keystore for it to be trusted?

Tags: java

I have imported a certificate into the java cacerts keystore but the certificate was generated through a private root CA domain. This means the issuer isn't listed in the list of existing certs in the store. Does this mean the cert is not trusted?

Comment: Did you test whatever needs it and it still gives a cert issue? If so, extract the root (and intermediary) from your cert and put those into the trust store and try again.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a certificate into keystore and the issuer of the certificate is not found or not trusted, the keytool asks you if the certificate should be trusted.
If you answer yes, then the certificate and all other certificates issued by that certificate are trusted.